# How we set the response timeout in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ajax, request, response, connection-timeout

**How I Increase the Timeout?**

```
var TIMEOUT = 300000; // 5m (default is 120000)
 
var server = https.createServer({timeout: TIMEOUT}, Process).listen(8080);
    server.timeout = TIMEOUT;

function Process(request, response)
{
    request.setTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    response.setTimeout(TIMEOUT);

    request.socket.setTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    response.socket.setTimeout(TIMEOUT);

    console.log('now is', req.socket.timeout); // => now, will display 300000.
    console.log('now is', server.timeout); // => now, will display 300000.

    request.on('close', function () {
        console.log('req close after', Date.now()-t); // => 120063
    });

    response.on('close', function () {
        console.log('res close after', Date.now()-t); // => 120064
    });
}
```

```
{timeout: TIMEOUT} => Does Not Work in Final
server.timeout = TIMEOUT => Does Not Work in Final
request.setTimeout(TIMEOUT) => Does Not Work in Final
response.setTimeout(TIMEOUT) => Does Not Work in Final
request.socket.setTimeout(TIMEOUT) => Does Not Work in Final
response.socket.setTimeout(TIMEOUT) => Does Not Work in Final
```

"req close after 120063". Why around 120000 (which is the default)?! Why not around 300000? even the "server.timeout" and "request.socket.timeout" will confirm the new timeout, but the final effect is like nothing was changed.

And the weirdest thing is, after some time, the request will be replicated on server, but on client side, on Network tab from Developer Tools, does not exist.

Comment: would you mind to explain what you want to acomplish, what you tried, and what was your (unwanted) result?

Comment: I have a similar problem using the nodeJS Elasticsearch client, despite explicitly setting timeout values, the node defaults are getting in the way.